# Is there a mapping that ties Credit Events to standard CDS documentation clauses?

Tags: cds, credit-derivatives, cdo

I'm trying to map the standard CDS documentation clauses that we receive from Markit:

- CR/CR14
- MR/MR14
- MM/MM14
- XR/XR14

to the credit event types that we are seeing:

- BANKRUPTCY
- FAILURE TO PAY
- RESTRUCTURING
- OBLIGATION ACCELERATION
- OBLIGATION DEFAULT
- REPUDIATION/MORATORIUM
- GOVERNMENTAL INTERVENTION

i.e. which events trigger which clauses, if that is well-defined?

The context is pricing CDOs, I'm trying to determine what auction price to pick up from the auction information in order to use as a recovery rate.

Comment: These doc clause definitions may help: https://www.isda.org/a/eXEDE/isda-2014-credit-definitions-faq-v12-clean.pdf . They cover a "redtructuring" event differently. But you are unlikely to get different quotes for different doc clauses of the same credit.

Comment: But there have been some more disputes about "government intervention" event post 2014 definitions, for example see https://blogs.orrick.com/derivatives/tag/governmental-intervention/ . And there may be more disputes about the 2022 Russian sovereign default.